# Running applications depending on battery or charging

Tags: power-management, battery

What are good program or script solutions to run specific applications depending on whether the laptop is running on battery or charging?

In order to conserve battery, I automatically want to stop certain applications from running when on battery (Dropbox, backup engine, etc...) and restart them when back on charging.

Comment: Take a look at the script discussed in this blog post: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/10/enable-laptop-mode-and-other-tweaks-to.html

Comment: @slm I cannot see how the linked information refers to my question of running certain applications depending on the AC stage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, You can below function

```
charging_status(){
    if upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep -qP "state:\s*discharging"
    then
        return 1
    else
        return 0
    fi
}
```

Comment: I am not using Ubuntu but Arch Linux. However, I also have `upower` installed. Where should I place this function?

Comment: Hi, You can use `monit` deamon to check charging status on specific intervals like every 10 seconds, and you can write monit script with help of above function, to close and open application. take look at below link : http://mmonit.com/monit/

Comment: Thanks for mmonit, looks what I need! Mind helping me with my `~/.monitrc`? I struggle with translating the above function into monit's language. This is what I have so far but I don't know how to properly add the grep/status component: `check program upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep -qP "state:\s*discharging"
      if status != 0 then exec "/usr/bin/dropboxd"
`

Answer (score 0):

The `on_ac_power` command allows you to detect whether the machine is plugged to the AC wall plug or running on batteries.

```
if /usr/bin/on_ac_power 
then 
   echo "Plugged to the AC"
else 
   echo "Running on batteries"
fi
```

Comment: Note that if system doesn't have battery (e.g. desktop system) `on_ac_power` returns exit code 255 which is considered `false` and this script would run the part that assumes system is running on batteries.